# ESP8226 micropython ssl connection issue with SMTP

Tags: ssl, smtp, gmail, esp8266, micropython

So after doing a lot of research I have been able to send SMTP email using Google's gmail server.  I am using the same code without issue in CPython on both Windows and Linux however when I try to use the code on Micropython 1.9.2 (Latest as of Sept 11th) on the ESP8266 or Unix port the code locks up on line 63 but I cannot figure out why.

Any recommendations on how to correct this would be greatly appreciated as I the only other thing I can think of is that Micropython's implementation of SSL is not sufficient and that I will need to attempt to port CPython SSL over.

Thank you.

Offending code is:

```
61    heloCommand = 'EHLO Alice\r\n'
62    ssl_clientSocket.write(heloCommand.encode())
63    recv1 = ssl_clientSocket.read(1024)
64    print(recv1)
```

CODE (Yes, I know it is ugly and plan to clean it up once working in micropython):

```
    # Micropython
try:
  import usocket as socket
  #import base64
  import ussl as ssl

except:
# Python version 3
  import socket
  #import base64
  import ssl


msg = """From: XXX@gmail.com
To: XXX@gmail.com
Subject: Testing

Testing transmission thru python
"""
endmsg = "\r\n.\r\n"

recipient = "XXX@gmail.com"
sender = "XXX@gmail.com"
username = "XXX@gmail.com"
password = 'Mary_Had_A_Password_of_123'

# Choose a mail server (e.g. Google mail server) and call it mailserver
mailserver = "smtp.gmail.com"
port = 587

# Create socket called clientSocket and establish a TCP connection with mailserver
clientSocket = socket.socket()
clientSocket.connect(socket.getaddrinfo(mailserver, port)[0][-1])
recv = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print(recv)
print(recv[:3])
if recv[:3] != b'220':
    print('220 reply not received from server.')

# Send HELO command and print server response.
heloCommand = 'EHLO Alice\r\n'
clientSocket.send(heloCommand.encode())
recv1 = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print(recv1)
if recv1[:3] != b'250':
    print('250 reply not received from server.')

# Request an encrypted connection
startTlsCommand = 'STARTTLS\r\n'
clientSocket.send(startTlsCommand.encode())
tls_recv = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print(tls_recv)
if tls_recv[:3] != b'220':
    print('220 reply not received from server')

# Encrypt the socket
#ssl_clientSocket = ssl.wrap_socket(clientSocket, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
ssl_clientSocket = ssl.wrap_socket(clientSocket)
print("Secure socket created")

heloCommand = 'EHLO Alice\r\n'
ssl_clientSocket.write(heloCommand.encode())
recv1 = ssl_clientSocket.read(1024)
print(recv1)

# Send the AUTH LOGIN command and print server response.
authCommand = 'AUTH LOGIN\r\n'
ssl_clientSocket.write(authCommand.encode())
auth_recv = ssl_clientSocket.read(1024)
print(auth_recv)
if auth_recv[:3] != b'334':
    print('334 reply not received from server')

print("Sending username / password")
# Send username and print server response.
#uname = base64.b64encode((username).encode())
uname=b'Base64EncryptedUser=='
pword=b'Base64EncryptedPassword'
print(str(uname))
ssl_clientSocket.write(uname)
ssl_clientSocket.write('\r\n'.encode())
uname_recv = ssl_clientSocket.read(1024)
print(uname_recv)
if uname_recv[:3] != b'334':
    print('334 reply not received from server')

# Send password and print server response.
#pword = base64.b64encode((password).encode())
print(str(pword))
ssl_clientSocket.write(pword)
ssl_clientSocket.write('\r\n'.encode())
pword_recv = ssl_clientSocket.read(1024)

print(pword_recv)
if pword_recv[:3] != b'235':
    print('235 reply not received from server')

# Send MAIL FROM command and print server response.
mailFromCommand = 'MAIL FROM: <' + sender + '>\r\n'
ssl_clientSocket.write(mailFromCommand.encode())
recv2 = ssl_clientSocket.read(1024)
print(recv2)
if recv2[:3] != b'250':
    print('250 reply not received from server.')

# Send RCPT TO command and print server response.
rcptToCommand = 'RCPT TO: <' + recipient + '>\r\n'
ssl_clientSocket.write(rcptToCommand.encode())
recv3 = ssl_clientSocket.read(1024)
print(recv3)
if recv3[:3] != b'250':
    print('250 reply not received from server.')

# Send DATA command and print server response.
dataCommand = 'DATA\r\n'
ssl_clientSocket.write(dataCommand.encode())
recv4 = ssl_clientSocket.read(1024)
print(recv4)
if recv4[:3] != b'354':
    print('354 reply not received from server.')

# Send message data.
ssl_clientSocket.write(msg.encode())

# Message ends with a single period.
ssl_clientSocket.write(endmsg.encode())
recv5 = ssl_clientSocket.read(1024)
print(recv5)
if recv5[:3] != b'250':
    print('250 reply not received from server.')

# Send QUIT command and get server response.
quitCommand = 'QUIT\r\n'
ssl_clientSocket.write(quitCommand.encode())
recv6 = ssl_clientSocket.read(1024)
print(recv6)
if recv6[:3] != b'221':
    print('221 reply not received from server.')

clientSocket.close()
```

UPDATED CODE WITH ACCEPTED ANSWER (Yes, I know it is ugly) with read(1024) being replaced with readline() for ssl socket.  Also needed to add a way to clean the buffer out after ssl EHLO command so added a "recvCount=recv1.decode().count('\n')" in first EHLO then a loop in the ssl EHLO for the same count:

```
    # Micropython
try:
  import usocket as socket
  #import base64
  import ussl as ssl

except:
# Python version 3
  import socket
  #import base64
  import ssl


msg = """From: XXX@gmail.com
To: XXX@gmail.com
Subject: Testing

Testing transmission thru python
"""
endmsg = "\r\n.\r\n"

recipient = "XXX@gmail.com"
sender = "XXX@gmail.com"
username = "XXX@gmail.com"
password = 'Mary_Had_A_Password_of_123'

# Choose a mail server (e.g. Google mail server) and call it mailserver
mailserver = "smtp.gmail.com"
port = 587

# Create socket called clientSocket and establish a TCP connection with mailserver
clientSocket = socket.socket()
clientSocket.connect(socket.getaddrinfo(mailserver, port)[0][-1])
recv = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print(recv)
print(recv[:3])
if recv[:3] != b'220':
    print('220 reply not received from server.')

# Send HELO command and print server response.
heloCommand = 'EHLO Alice\r\n'
clientSocket.send(heloCommand.encode())
recv1 = clientSocket.recv(1024)
recvCount=recv1.decode().count('\n')
print(recv1)
if recv1[:3] != b'250':
    print('250 reply not received from server.')

# Request an encrypted connection
startTlsCommand = 'STARTTLS\r\n'
clientSocket.send(startTlsCommand.encode())
tls_recv = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print(tls_recv)
if tls_recv[:3] != b'220':
    print('220 reply not received from server')

# Encrypt the socket
#ssl_clientSocket = ssl.wrap_socket(clientSocket, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
ssl_clientSocket = ssl.wrap_socket(clientSocket)
print("Secure socket created")

heloCommand = 'EHLO Alice\r\n'
ssl_clientSocket.write(heloCommand.encode())
recv1=''
for index in range(0,recvCount):
  recv1 = recv1+ssl_clientSocket.readline().decode()
print(recv1)

# Send the AUTH LOGIN command and print server response.
authCommand = 'AUTH LOGIN\r\n'
ssl_clientSocket.write(authCommand.encode())
auth_recv = ssl_clientSocket.readline()
print(auth_recv)
if auth_recv[:3] != b'334':
    print('334 reply not received from server')

print("Sending username / password")
# Send username and print server response.
#uname = base64.b64encode((username).encode())
uname=b'Base64EncryptedUser=='
pword=b'Base64EncryptedPassword'
print(str(uname))
ssl_clientSocket.write(uname)
ssl_clientSocket.write('\r\n'.encode())
uname_recv = ssl_clientSocket.readline()
print(uname_recv)
if uname_recv[:3] != b'334':
    print('334 reply not received from server')

# Send password and print server response.
#pword = base64.b64encode((password).encode())
print(str(pword))
ssl_clientSocket.write(pword)
ssl_clientSocket.write('\r\n'.encode())
pword_recv = ssl_clientSocket.readline()

print(pword_recv)
if pword_recv[:3] != b'235':
    print('235 reply not received from server')

# Send MAIL FROM command and print server response.
mailFromCommand = 'MAIL FROM: <' + sender + '>\r\n'
ssl_clientSocket.write(mailFromCommand.encode())
recv2 = ssl_clientSocket.readline()
print(recv2)
if recv2[:3] != b'250':
    print('250 reply not received from server.')

# Send RCPT TO command and print server response.
rcptToCommand = 'RCPT TO: <' + recipient + '>\r\n'
ssl_clientSocket.write(rcptToCommand.encode())
recv3 = ssl_clientSocket.readline()
print(recv3)
if recv3[:3] != b'250':
    print('250 reply not received from server.')

# Send DATA command and print server response.
dataCommand = 'DATA\r\n'
ssl_clientSocket.write(dataCommand.encode())
recv4 = ssl_clientSocket.readline()
print(recv4)
if recv4[:3] != b'354':
    print('354 reply not received from server.')

# Send message data.
ssl_clientSocket.write(msg.encode())

# Message ends with a single period.
ssl_clientSocket.write(endmsg.encode())
recv5 = ssl_clientSocket.readline()
print(recv5)
if recv5[:3] != b'250':
    print('250 reply not received from server.')

# Send QUIT command and get server response.
quitCommand = 'QUIT\r\n'
ssl_clientSocket.write(quitCommand.encode())
recv6 = ssl_clientSocket.readline()
print(recv6)
if recv6[:3] != b'221':
    print('221 reply not received from server.')

clientSocket.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> recv1 = ssl_clientSocket.read(1024)

Please read about about MicroPython stream semantics (which closely matches Python stream semantics, just with some simplifications):
http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/pyboard/library/uio.html?#conceptual-hierarchy

What the quoted statement does is requesting exactly 1024 of data (MicroPython follows "buffered stream" Python semantics by default). If there's not that much of data, `.read()` will patiently wait until enough arrives (or until EOF or error happens).

SMTP protocol is line-oriented, so you need to use `.readline()` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your insight, took a little tweaking but your recommendation worked.  Will review the attached documentation (double thank you).